# Using fscanf in binary mode

Tags: c, scanf, ppm

Is using fscanf when opening a file in binary mode bad? I can't seem to find anything reasonable on the Internet. I am trying to open and read a PPM file and I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693631/read-ppm-file-and-store-it-in-an-array-coded-with-c), but I am not sure if using fscanf is okay? And using netpbm is not okay, yeah.

Reading this with fread seems like a pain.

Comment: http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html This. I am most confused about: Each sample is represented in pure binary by either 1 or 2 bytes.

So I guess I have to read it in binary mode.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that...

Comment: sarcasm - i know it is the lowest form of whit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scanf` and `fscanf` functions are for reading characters, e.g., "1234", and converting them from a string to an integer. But integers are not stored as stings in a binary file. The actual bytes of the integer itself are stored. These need to be read directly into an integer with `fread`.

Comment: Okay, now I understand why it would work if I open the file in text mode if all the values are <= 255. That would be enough for me.